# Unnaming a range in VB blows up (Excel 2003, VB 6.5)

Tags: vba, excel, range, rename, excel-2003

I am trying to unname a range if cells if it exists. The code below finds the range with the right name, but explodes at nm.Delete line, without any explanation. How can I fix/debug it?

Thanks!

```
Function unefineRange(strRgeName As String)
    Dim nm As Name
    For Each nm In ThisWorkbook.Names
        If nm.Name = strRgeName Then
            nm.Delete
        End If
    Next nm
End Function
```

Comment: Could it have anything to do with the fact that you're deleting names, while iterating over a list of all names. You're essentially changing the list as you iterate over it.

Comment: Unlikely. I tried to set a boolean flag to true inside the loop, and delete the range outside the loop; got the same "result".

Comment: `but explodes at nm.Delete line` - you really get no error message? What does it do when it `explodes'?

Comment: executions stops, I get #value in the cell that contains the name of the function

Comment: Is this code in a VBA Module or on the Sheet code? Sometimes VBA doesn't behave nicely when the code is stored in something that's being changed...

Comment: you are trying to run this from as UDF? If so, did you try it in the VBE in a standard module?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just ran this in Excel 2003 and it ran fine:

I created two named ranges, Fred and Wilma, and ran this (module 1) in the Visual Basic editor. Deleted "Wilma" with no problems.

```
Function undefineRange(strRgeName As String)
    Dim nm As Name
    For Each nm In ThisWorkbook.Names
        If nm.Name = strRgeName Then
            nm.Delete
        End If
    Next nm
End Function

Sub unDefineRangePlease()
   undefineRange ("Wilma")
End Sub
```

Comment: How are you calling your function?

Comment: It was something else, sorry should not have asked this.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Sub DeleteName(strRgeName As String)
    On Error Resume Next  ' so if name does not exist no error is raised
    ThisWorkbook.Names(strRgeName).Delete
End Sub
```

I changed to a `Sub`, I see no reason for it to be a `Function`, since you are not setting a return value